# What does the Bard's ability do in Battleheart?

Tags: battleheart

This question refers to the iPhone game [Battleheart](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battleheart/id394057299?mt=8).

The Cleric's standard ability heals allies, and it's totally obvious what's going on as life bars go up.

The Bard's standard ability is also cast on allies, but it's not clear what effect the spell is having. What exactly does the Bard's ability do?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a guess, but judging from the LV10 abilities of the bard:

```
Gusto - The power bonus granted to your target is increased by 50%.
Stoicism - The armor bonus granted to your target is increased by 50%.
```

I think it gives armor, and attack power bonus to the target, but no clue on how much.

Answer (score 2):

The developer stated, on the Touch Arcade boards, that it adds the bard's power to the target's Power and Armor stats.

Here it is:
http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=1573923#post1573923

> The bard's buff essentially adds his power to both the power and armor of his target... but not exactly. The thing is, it doesn't get multiplied by certain powers, like a rogue's sneak attack. It's just extra damage (or healing) added on to each thing you do... again, this is halved for the barbarian since he generally attacks twice as fast. So in short, you can pretty much consider a bard with 30 power as granting his target 30 levels worth of power/armor, except when it comes to certain cooldowns.

Answer (score 0):

It adds the Bard's stats to the target stats, specifically power and armor.